# Headless Firefox in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, headless, headless-browser

I want to run firefox headless.

Not hide the browser window or open it in a virtual desktop, Firefox supports headless mode by using "-headless" flag.

Problem is I know how to do it in chrome but not in Firefox.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace MyApp {
public partial class Form1: Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        IWebDriver driver;
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.AddArguments("--headless");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    }
}
}
```

My WinForm application only has a button with name StartBtn.
On clicking of the button Firefox should run headless, but it opens in a normal window.

---

**Update**
I updated firefox to 56.0.1

Now I get a different error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException'
>   occurred in WebDriver.dll
>
> Additional information: Expected browser binary location, but unable
>   to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary'
>   capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Headless mode in Firefox is supported from version 56 on Windows and Mac OS. Ensure that you have the correct version installed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode#Browser_support

With **Firefox v56.0.1**, **Selenium.WebDriver v3.6.0** and **geckodriver v0.19.0 (x64)** this works correctly for me.

Regarding the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Ensure you're using the correct version of `geckodriver`. I suspect you're using the `x32` build on an `x64` machine, get the `x64` build.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: it shows an exception when I use `--headless`. **All arguments must start with two dashes ('--'); argument '-headless' does not.**

Comment: I updated firefox to the latest version, I now get a different error. Please check my updated question.

Comment: @Raven Which version of `geckodriver` are you using? I think you're probably using 32-bit on a 64-bit system. Try the x64 version: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: Replacing the 32bit geckodriver with the 64bit worked. Big Thank you!