# How to run my Selenium Project in Headless mode?

Tags: c#, selenium, geckodriver, headless

I'm unable to execute with all the answers in internet, of how I can execute this porject in headless mode.

This is an example of how I run my project:

```
namespace Automation.TestCases
{
    public class MailContactManagement
    {

        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(VariablesConstants.BaseURL);
            ActionModules.SignIn(driver);
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".badge-initials-mini")).Displayed);
        }

        [Test]
        [Ignore("Ignore Test")]
        public void TC_3340() // Create Mail
```

Comment: Which version of Firefox and geckodriver do you have? According to [this question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848615/headless-firefox-in-selenium-c-sharp) there is minimum version needed. And if you have the right version, what is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Headless Firefox in Selenium C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848615/headless-firefox-in-selenium-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you trying to run TC_3340? You realize that you have an Ignore set on it?

Comment: HTMLUnit works pretty well for this... there's also a headless option for ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `--headless` argument when starting the browser:

```
  FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
  options.addArguments("--headless");
  WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
  driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

(this example is in Java.. C# will allow something similar)

Comment: Not sure if its already fixed on windows, do u know anything about that? I know u don't need it if u running on Mac or Linux like.

Comment: it's been fixed for over a year